# How can I count the changes per row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some time aware data as below with group, date and id. Here id is the id of person handling the group for that specific month. What I wanted to get is how many times there has been changes in the persons handling the group.

```
group   date     ID
A      Jan-22    1
A      Feb-22    1
A      Mar-22    1
A      Apr-22    2
A      May-22    3
A      Jun-22    4
B      Mar-23    6
B      Apr-23    6
B      May-23    3
B      Jun-23    3
C      Sep-21    1
C      Oct-21    1
C      Nov-21    4
C      Dec-21    4
C      Jan-22    4
```

So the output should be something like the below. E.g. for "Group A" there are 4 person who handled since Jan-22 to June-22. And the changes are marked in the "id_changes" column in a cumulative manner.

Could you please be able to help in getting the output like this? I have tried a couple of times but unable to achieve it.

```
group   date     ID    id_changes
A      Jan-22    1         0
A      Feb-22    1         0
A      Mar-22    1         0
A      Apr-22    2         1
A      May-22    3         2
A      Jun-22    4         3
B      Mar-23    6         0
B      Apr-23    6         0
B      May-23    3         1
B      Jun-23    3         1
C      Sep-21    1         0
C      Oct-21    1         0
C      Nov-21    4         1
C      Dec-21    4         1
C      Jan-22    4         1
```

Comment: Please show the effort (your code) you have made so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet now correctly calculates the changes in the "ID" column within each group and then accumulates these changes to calculate the "id_changes" column as you specified in your desired output.    import pandas as pd

```
# Sample data
data = {
    "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"],
    "date": ["Jan-22", "Feb-22", "Mar-22", "Apr-22", "May-22", "Jun-22",
             "Mar-23", "Apr-23", "May-23", "Jun-23", "Sep-21", "Oct-21", "Nov-21", "Dec-21", "Jan-22"],
    "ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert date column to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b-%y')

# Sort the DataFrame by group and date
df = df.sort_values(by=['group', 'date'])

# Calculate the changes in ID within each group
df['id_changes'] = df.groupby('group')['ID'].diff().fillna(0)

# Reset id_changes to 0 where ID changes
df.loc[df['id_changes'] != 0, 'id_changes'] = 1

# Calculate cumulative changes in id_changes within each group
df['id_changes'] = df.groupby('group')['id_changes'].cumsum()

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   group       date  ID  id_changes
0      A 2022-01-01   1         0.0
1      A 2022-02-01   1         0.0
2      A 2022-03-01   1         0.0
3      A 2022-04-01   2         1.0
4      A 2022-05-01   3         2.0
5      A 2022-06-01   4         3.0
6      B 2023-03-01   6         0.0
7      B 2023-04-01   6         0.0
8      B 2023-05-01   3         1.0
9      B 2023-06-01   3         1.0
10     C 2021-09-01   1         0.0
11     C 2021-10-01   1         0.0
12     C 2021-11-01   4         1.0
13     C 2021-12-01   4         1.0
14     C 2022-01-01   4         1.0
```

Comment: IMO care should be taken before applying `%b` when parsing dates as far as it depends on the current locale.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The date column I have is already been offset to MonthEnd, so the issue was resolved for parsing dates.

Comment: The above solution works perfectly as expected although the id column I had was object, I had to convert to int due to diff. which has no impact on the output.

Answer (score 1):

If we are looking for changes, not the number of different ID, then assuming the date column is sorted we could use `diff` in pair with `astype(bool)` before applying `cumsum`:

```
(
   df.groupby('group')
   .apply(lambda df:
      df['ID'].diff().fillna(0).astype(bool).cumsum()
   ).reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the pandas library.

Store the data in a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'date': ['Jan-22', 'Feb-22', 'Mar-22', 'Apr-22', 'May-22', 'Jun-22', 'Mar-23', 'Apr-23', 'May-23', 'Jun-23', 'Sep-21', 'Oct-21', 'Nov-21', 'Dec-21', 'Jan-22'],
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b-%y')

df.sort_values(by=['group', 'date'], inplace=True)

df_grouped = df.groupby('group')

df['id_changes'] = df_grouped['ID'].diff().ne(0)

df['id_changes'] = df_grouped['id_changes'].cumsum()

df['id_changes'] = df['id_changes'] - 1
print(df)
```

Explanation code.

I use the pandas library to handle data, this is generally a good approach but you're free to choose any other data library you want.
I make a dictionary of your data, since you don't provide where your data is coming from (database, file,???).

1. Create a `DataFrame` object to start processing the data.
2. Format the date, so comparison is easier.
3. Group by `group` and `date`, this makes so the 'counting' of `id_changes` is easier
4. `df_grouped['ID'].diff().ne(0)`: It **identifies** the points where the ID changes see [this for diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and [this for ne](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html)
5. .`cumsum()` **accumulates** the `id_changes` [check here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)